# Tableau JS Filter: Pass filters from one dashboard to all others

Tags: javascript, tableau-api

I am relatively new to JavaScript and the Tableau JS API.  I am trying to get the filters from one embedded visualization and pass it to other visualizations on the web page.

I am initializing my main visualization with this code.

```
function initViz() {

var containerDiv = document.getElementById("vizContainer"),

    url = "https://tableau.Viz",
    options = {
        hideTabs: true,
        loadorder: -1,
        hideToolbar: true,
        onFirstInteractive: function () {
            workbook=SumDash.getWorkbook();
            activeSheet = workbook.getActiveSheet().getWorksheets()[0];
            SumDash.addEventListener(tableau.TableauEventName.FILTER_CHANGE,onFilterChange);
            console.log("Run this code when the viz1 has finished loading.");
        }
    };      
var SumDash = new tableau.Viz(containerDiv, url, options);
```

When filters are changed on the main visualization, I am getting the field names and applied values and updating the other visualizations with this code.

This code works, but it is very slow.  I think part of my problem is that the dashboard I am getting the filters from has multiple worksheets and the below code is looping through each worksheet in the dashboard (21 worksheets on the dashboard and console.log(1) is printing 21 times).

Is there a way to only pass the field names and values from one worksheet and not each worksheet in the dashboard?  Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
function onFilterChange(){
 activeSheet.getFiltersAsync()
.then(function(promise) {
    console.log(1);
    var fieldName = [];
    var fieldValArr = [];
    for (var i=0;  i< promise.length; i++) {
        fieldName.push(promise[i].getFieldName());
        var  fieldValues = [];
        for (var j=0;  j< promise[i].getAppliedValues().length; j++) {
            fieldValues[j] = promise[i].getAppliedValues()[j].value;
        }

    fieldValArr.push(fieldValues);
    for (var k=0; k<fieldName.length; k++){
        activeSheet1.applyFilterAsync(fieldName[k], fieldValArr[k], tableau.FilterUpdateType.REPLACE);
        activeSheet2.applyFilterAsync(fieldName[k], fieldValArr[k], tableau.FilterUpdateType.REPLACE);
    }
  }
})
```

Thanks!

Tableau Desktop version =  2018.1

https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/tableau-2.min.js

Comment: Are you all of the embedded worksheets coming from the same workbook? Are you using data extracts or live connections?

Comment: All of the embedded worksheets are from the same workbook, and the connections are live.

Comment: hi @TyM, i am also facing a similar issue, where the performance seems to be very slow, if you have already fixed this, can you please share your approach?